# drupal 8 rest api: get allowed values for list field

Tags: rest, api, drupal-modules, drupal-8, listfield

I am not a drupal dev, and i know next to nothing of php specifically. That said, I am developing a new interface for an existing drupal website and we will continue to use drupal in headless mode using the rest api while we migrate to a better long term solution.

Exposing custom content types be pretty straightforward for the most part, but one aspect is giving me a headache: it seems impossible to expose the list of allowed values in a list field (e.g. list of decimals, integers or text). Ideally, there would be a way to query the drupal api for a given field name, returning a list of possible values for that field.

The closest I've gotten is through the `entity rest extra` module [found here](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_rest_extra).

but while it exposes a ton of info on the fields, even default value for the list field, the allowed values are not there.

Is there a way to expose the allowed values list in the restful api?

Since the module I found is *so close* to what I need, would it be easily implemented by custom patching my drupal php code? where should I look for clues?

thanks in advance